# Cannot save Dictionary to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

> EDIT : i managed to save , but data is duplicating. How to fix. Here is the screenshot :
> [image]

I'm trying to save a Dictionary values in a csv file. This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

r= requests.get("https://www.assamcareer.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')
root = soup.find_all('div', class_='post-outer')
for title in root:
    getTitle = title.a.text
    link = title.a['href']
    detail_page_requests = requests.get(link)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(detail_page_requests.content,'html5lib')
    getDetails = soup2.find('div', class_='post-body entry-content')
    ads = getDetails.find_all('ins',class_='adsbygoogle')
    for removeAds in ads:
        removeAds.decompose()
        newDetail = getDetails
        mydict={
            'title': getTitle,
            'links' : link,
            'desc' : newDetail
        }
        # print(len(mydict)) 
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index').T.to_csv('Cr_pt.csv', index=False,mode='a')
```

I'm getting this Error:

> ```
> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
> ```

How to save this dictionary in csv file without any errors?

Comment: No need to use pandas. Just use csv DictWriter. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Answer (score 2):

use `from_dict` with `orient="index"`
eg:

```
d = dict(zip((list("amirsaleem")), list(range(10))))
```

d:

```
{'a': 5, 'm': 9, 'i': 2, 'r': 3, 's': 4, 'l': 6, 'e': 8}
```

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
```

```
   0
a  5
m  9
i  2
r  3
s  4
l  6
e  8
```

Comment: I did it Sir, but now the data is duplicating. I have edited the question. Pls have a look.I added the full code as well @Amir